# Entity Framework Generic Repository vs Direct Queries on Context

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, repository-pattern

Generic Repository and Entity Framework:
I am planning to use a Generic Repository to handle queries on the context and noticed (using SQL server profiler) that the filter expression is not being translated and included in the SQL query made to the database. Just wondering whether this kind of overload is expected when using generic repository?
Repository Code:

```
public class BaseRepositories<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{

    private readonly DbContext _CurrentObjectContext;
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _EntityObjectSet;

    public BaseRepositories(DbContext currentObjectContext)
    {
        _CurrentObjectContext = currentObjectContext;
        _EntityObjectSet = _CurrentObjectContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public DbSet<TEntity> EntityObjectSet
    {
        get
        {
            return _EntityObjectSet;
        }
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> Query(Func<TEntity, bool> expression, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] navigationProperties)
    {
        var ReturnSetQueryable = _EntityObjectSet.Where(expression);
        return ReturnSetQueryable.AsQueryable();
    }

}
```

Calls made to the repository and on context and the SQL query from the profiler
a)  Using Repository:

Code:

```
        var UserRepository = new BaseRepositories<user>(new DbContext());


        var UsersQuery = UserRepository.Query(v => v.name == "ajayr");

        var FirstUser = UsersQuery.FirstOrDefault();
```

Query form the Sql Profiler:

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[guid] AS [guid], 
    [Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
    [Extent1].[name] AS [name], 
    [Extent1].[password] AS [password], 
    [Extent1].[first_name] AS [first_name], 
    [Extent1].[middle_name] AS [middle_name], 
    [Extent1].[last_name] AS [last_name], 
    [Extent1].[email_address] AS [email_address], 
    [Extent1].[url] AS [url], 
    [Extent1].[account_enabled] AS [account_enabled], 
    [Extent1].[user_id] AS [user_id], 
    [Extent1].[last_update] AS [last_update], 
    [Extent1].[deleted] AS [deleted], 
    [Extent1].[employee_id] AS [employee_id], 
    [Extent1].[rec_source] AS [rec_source], 
    [Extent1].[last_login_date] AS [last_login_date], 
    [Extent1].[last_email_update] AS [last_email_update], 
    [Extent1].[invalid_email_adr] AS [invalid_email_adr]
    FROM [dbo].[users] AS [Extent1]

b)  Direct Query on the Context:

Code:

```
       DbContext db = new DbContext();

        DbSet<user> usersset = db.Set<user>();

       var UserQueryWithFilter =  usersset.Where(v => v.name == "ajayr");

       var FirstUser = tesst.FirstOrDefault();
```

Query form the Sql Profiler:

SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[guid] AS [guid], 
    [Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
    [Extent1].[name] AS [name], 
    [Extent1].[password] AS [password], 
    [Extent1].[first_name] AS [first_name], 
    [Extent1].[middle_name] AS [middle_name], 
    [Extent1].[last_name] AS [last_name], 
    [Extent1].[email_address] AS [email_address], 
    [Extent1].[url] AS [url], 
    [Extent1].[account_enabled] AS [account_enabled], 
    [Extent1].[user_id] AS [user_id], 
    [Extent1].[last_update] AS [last_update], 
    [Extent1].[deleted] AS [deleted], 
    [Extent1].[employee_id] AS [employee_id], 
    [Extent1].[rec_source] AS [rec_source], 
    [Extent1].[last_login_date] AS [last_login_date], 
    [Extent1].[last_email_update] AS [last_email_update], 
    [Extent1].[invalid_email_adr] AS [invalid_email_adr]
    FROM [dbo].[users] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE 'ajayr' = [Extent1].[name]

Comment: Have you considered just returning the IQueryable and not accepting an Expression as a parameter? This will allow you to either filter using a linq extension (where, single, first etc.) or return the entire dataset without having to pass an expression through telling query to return the whole dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide function, not an expression as a parameter. I think you need to slightly change a syntax

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> Query(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] navigationProperties)
{
    var ReturnSetQueryable = _EntityObjectSet.Where(expression);
    return ReturnSetQueryable.AsQueryable();
}
```